# What's the .Net replacement for File.Type FileSystemObject property?

Tags: .net, filesystemobject

In classic Asp we used the [File.Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7k0wsxy(VS.85).aspx) property to get the friendly name associated with a file type from the registry (e.g. "Text Document" for ".txt"). The FileInfo class which generally replaces the old COM object doesn't replicate this feature and so far I'm not having much success in my search of a replacement.

Comment: I think it has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437382/get-file-type-in-c

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437382/get-file-type-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a method in the BCL, but you could easily read it from the Registry:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string extension = ".txt";
        string nicename = "";

        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(extension))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                string filetype = key.GetValue(null) as string;
                using (RegistryKey keyType = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(filetype))
                {
                    if (keyType != null)
                    {
                        nicename = keyType.GetValue(null) as string;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(nicename);

    }
}
```

However, the method used in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437382/get-file-type-in-c) provided by Vladimir is to be preferred as it uses an API interface.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid reading the values manually but given the options I may may go this route