# Get file information from recursive folders

Tags: c#, winforms

What I'd like to do is get 6 pieces of file information from every file in a folder, and all folders beneath it.  These pieces are:

- Type (you can do this in Access, it will return "Microsoft Excel Worksheet" or "Winzip File" or something, just like you see in the Explorer window, but I didn't see a property for this in C#)
- FullName
- Length
- CreationTime
- LastAccessTime
- LastWriteTime

I have the following code, which will spit out a list of files complete with path, but I'm trying to figure out how to get that additional info in my output.  If it can be separated by a semicolon or something, that would be good as the eventual desire is to write this info to a table.  Any help is appreciated.

```
    private void GetMyFiles () {
        string rootDirectory = @"" + txtPathToScan.Text + "";
        string extension = "*";

        List<string> files = GetFilesRecursively (rootDirectory, extension);

        Console.WriteLine ("Got {0} files of extension {1} in directory {2}", files.Count, extension, rootDirectory);
        foreach (string file in files) {
            Console.WriteLine (file);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function calls itself recursively for each of the subdirectories that it finds
    /// in the root directory passed to it. It returns files of the extension as specified
    /// by the caller.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rootDirectory">The directory from which the file list is sought.</param>
    /// <param name="extension">The particular extension for which the file list is sought.</param>
    /// <returns>A list of all the files with extension as specified by the caller. This list
    /// includes the files in the current directory as well its sub-directories.</returns>
    static List<string> GetFilesRecursively (string rootDirectory, string extension) {
        // Uncomment this line only if you want to trace the control as it goes from
        // sub-directory to sub-directory. Be ready for long scrolls of text output:
        //Console.WriteLine ("Currently in directory {0}", rootDirectory);

        // Create an output list:
        List<string> opList = new List<string> ();

        // Get all files in the current directory:
        string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles (rootDirectory, "*." + extension);

        // Add these files to the output list:
        opList.AddRange (allFiles);

        // Get all sub-directories in current directory:
        string[] subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories (rootDirectory);

        // And iterate through them:
        foreach (string subDir in subDirectories) {
            // Get all the files from the sub-directory:
            List<string> subDirFileList = GetFilesRecursively (subDir, extension);
            // And add it to this list:
            opList.AddRange (subDirFileList);
        }

        // Finally return the output list:
        return opList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get most of these using the [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) class....

```
var info = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"c:\folder\file.ext");
```

It has properties for `Length`, `CreationTime`, `LastAccessTime` and `LastWriteTime`, to output them (for example) to the console, you could do...

```
Console.WriteLine("For file {0}", info.Name);
Console.WriteLine("Length is {0}", info.Length);
Console.WriteLine("Creation time is {0}", info.CreationTime);
Console.WriteLine("Last access time is {0}", info.LastAccessTime);
Console.WriteLine("Last write time is {0}", info.LastWriteTime);
```

To get the full filename, you can use [`GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx)...

```
var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@"c:\folder\file.ext")
```

`filename` will equal `"file"` in the above example.

Getting the description of a file extension is a bit more work, but can be done using [`SHGetFIleInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb762179.aspx), See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3780110/39709) for details.

To integrate this with your current code (if you're not so worried about the file descriptions), you could change your `GetFilesRecursively` method to return a `List<FileInfo>`...

```
static List<FileInfo> GetFilesRecursively (string rootDirectory, string extension)
```

Update your `opList` variable accordingly...

```
List<FileInfo> opList = new List<FileInfo> ();
```

And then tweak your `AddRange` call to add `FileInfo` objects...

```
opList.AddRange (allFiles.Select(f => new FileInfo(f)));
```

Lastly, the type of `subDirFileList` will need to be changed as well, so a `List<FileInfo>`.

(I think that's everything!)

Comment: How would I integrate this into what I already have, to get what I'm looking for?  We'll leave out the SHGetFileInfo piece for now as that's more complex.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, the completed answer is as below.  Please **only** vote for Richard's answer if you're going to upvote anything.  Thanks!

```
    private void GetMyFiles () {
        string rootDirectory = @"" + txtPathToScan.Text + "";
        string extension = "*";

        List<FileInfo> files = GetFilesRecursively (rootDirectory, extension);

        Console.WriteLine ("Got {0} files of extension {1} in directory {2}", files.Count, extension, rootDirectory);
        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
            var info = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"" + file + "");

            Console.WriteLine("For file {0}", info.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Length is {0} KB", info.Length/1024);
            Console.WriteLine("Creation time is {0}", info.CreationTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Last access time is {0}", info.LastAccessTime);
            Console.WriteLine("Last write time is {0}", info.LastWriteTime);

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function calls itself recursively for each of the subdirectories that it finds
    /// in the root directory passed to it. It returns files of the extension as specified
    /// by the caller.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rootDirectory">The directory from which the file list is sought.</param>
    /// <param name="extension">The particular extension for which the file list is sought.</param>
    /// <returns>A list of all the files with extension as specified by the caller. This list
    /// includes the files in the current directory as well its sub-directories.</returns>
    static List<FileInfo> GetFilesRecursively(string rootDirectory, string extension)
    {
        // Uncomment this line only if you want to trace the control as it goes from
        // sub-directory to sub-directory. Be ready for long scrolls of text output:
        //Console.WriteLine ("Currently in directory {0}", rootDirectory);

        // Create an output list:
        List<FileInfo> opList = new List<FileInfo>();

        // Get all files in the current directory:
        string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles (rootDirectory, "*." + extension);

        // Add these files to the output list:
        opList.AddRange(allFiles.Select(f => new FileInfo(f)));

        // Get all sub-directories in current directory:
        string[] subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories (rootDirectory);

        // And iterate through them:
        foreach (string subDir in subDirectories) {
            // Get all the files from the sub-directory:
            List<FileInfo> subDirFileList = GetFilesRecursively (subDir, extension);
            // And add it to this list:
            opList.AddRange (subDirFileList);
        }

        // Finally return the output list:
        return opList;
    }
```