# C#: How can I retrieve the description of a folder?

Tags: c#

All folders have a type: Most of them are named "File folder", but some are called "Mediaserver" or "Local harddrive" (Translations). How do I retrieve those folder types using C#?
I found this for files: [How can I get the description of a file extension in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780028/how-can-i-get-the-description-of-a-file-extension-in-net)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[SHGetFileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the function you need. You need to pass the flag `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` as parameter to `dwFileAttributes` parameter.

Based on the [same answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3780110/2530848) I've modified the code to make it work for directories.

```
public static string GetFileFolderTypeDescription(string fileNameOrExtension)
{
    SHFILEINFO shfi;
    if (IntPtr.Zero != SHGetFileInfo(
                        fileNameOrExtension,
                        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY,
                        out shfi,
                        (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SHFILEINFO)),
                        SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES | SHGFI_TYPENAME))
    {
        return shfi.szTypeName;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works great. I forgot the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`.

Answer (score 5):

There a file called `desktop.ini` in every folder, which contains the translated folder description and icon for the folder in INI file format. Maybe you need to read that.

I found that for system folders, this references resources within system DLLs, so it may not be as simple as it seems.

That being said, you can also try the [SHGetFileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to obtain that information.

---

Just saw that Sriram Sakthivel gave a very nice answer using `SHGetFileInfo`, so go for that.

Comment: You just educated me about the *desktop.ini*. Thanks