# Get file information using Delphi windows api

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-xe

Using Delphi and Windows API is possible from a PItemIDList to get if the file is a folder or not? With this snippet of code I can get the only the name of the file.

```
procedure TMain.FolderMonitorFileChange(aSender: TObject; aPIDL: PItemIDList);
var
  FileInfo : SHFILEINFOW;
begin
  SHGetFileInfo(LPCTSTR(aPIDL), 0 , FileInfo, SizeOf(FileInfo), SHGFI_PIDL or SHGFI_DISPLAYNAME or SHGFI_TYPENAME or SHGFI_ATTRIBUTES);
  ShowMessage('File change notification: ' + FileInfo.szDisplayName + ' ' + FileInfo.szTypeName );
end;
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780028/how-can-i-get-the-description-of-a-file-extension-in-net

Comment: @Paul He has a PIDL and not a file

Comment: Call `IShellFolder::GetAttributesOf` and check for `SFGAO_FOLDER`.

Answer (score 4):

For a relative PIDL, you can obtain the [`IShellFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775075.aspx) interface of the PIDL's parent folder, and then pass the PIDL to the [`IShellFolder::GetAttributesOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775068.aspx) method.

```
function IsFolder(Parent: IShellFolder; aChildPIDL: PItemIDList): Boolean;
var
  Attrs: SFGAOF;
begin
  Result := Succeeded(Parent.GetAttributesOf(1, @aChildPidl, @Attrs))
    and (Attrs and SFGAO_FOLDER <> 0);
end;
```

For an absolute PIDL, you have a few different options:

- pass the PIDL to [`SHBindToParent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762114.aspx) to convert it to a relative PIDL and retrieve its parent folder's `IShellFolder`, then call `IShellFolder::GetAttributesOf()`.

  ```
  function IsFolder(aPIDL: PItemIDList): Boolean;
  var
    Parent: IShellFolder;
    Child: PItemIDList;
    Attrs: SFGAOF;
  begin
    Result := Succeeded(SHBindToParent(aPidl, IShellFolder, @Parent, @Child))
      and Succeeded(Parent.GetAttributesOf(1, @Child, @Attrs))
      and (Attrs and SFGAO_FOLDER <> 0);
  end;
  ```
- pass the PIDL to [`SHGetFileInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762179.aspx) using the `SHGFI_PIDL` flag.  Enable the `SHGFI_ATTRIBUTES` flag to request the item's attributes.

  ```
  function IsFolder(aPIDL: PItemIDList): Boolean;
  var
    FileInfo : SHFILEINFO;
  begin
    Result := (SHGetFileInfo(LPCTSTR(aPIDL), 0, @FileInfo, SizeOf(FileInfo), SHGFI_PIDL or  SHGFI_ATTRIBUTES) <> 0)
      and (FileInfo.dwAttributes and SFGAO_FOLDER <> 0);
  end;
  ```
- pass the PIDL to [`SHCreateItemFromIDList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762133.aspx) to retrieve an [`IShellItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761144.aspx) interface for it, and then call [`IShellItem::GetAttributes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761138.aspx).

  ```
  function IsFolder(aPIDL: PItemIDList): Boolean;
  var
    Item: IShellItem;
    Attrs: SFGAOF;
  begin
    Result := Succeeded(SHCreateItemFromIDList(aPidl, IShellItem, @Item))
      and Succeeded(Item.GetAttributes(SFGAO_FOLDER, @Attrs))
      and (Attrs and SFGAO_FOLDER <> 0);
  end;
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but the code does not work for me because that event returns to me file changes of a monitorized folder, and when a file is modified all is ok but when i create a file it triggers that the folder that contains that has been changed and the attribute says that is a file, the typename says 'file' and the displayName is the name of the folder.

Comment: You asked how to determine whether a PIDL represents a folder or a file. I answered that. The `SFGAO_FOLDER` attribute is specifically designed for that purpose. Now, you are describing a different issue.  Whether the notification gives you a file PIDL or a folder PIDL depends on what you are actually monitoring and how you are monitoring it. But I highly doubt that a folder object would not report itself as a folder in attributes, which makes me think either there is a bug in your code, or an error is being reported that you are not handling.

Comment: Yes I asked this because as you can see at the code I receive a 'PItemIDList' with the event, I thought that I do not know how to extract the data of that object. I am using a 'TLMDShellNotify' to monitor a folder and receive the changes using the 'FileChange' event of this object.