# How to get File Type of a file

Tags: vb.net, file, types

Is there a way to get the file type displayed in windows explorer in VB.net

i.e in windows explorer in details view one can see for example

```
Name          Date Modified           Type                           Size
A.PDF         05/06/2017 5:54PM       Adobe Acrobat reader           150kb
B.DOCX        05/06/2017 5:00PM       Microsoft Word Document        100kb
etc.
```

I want to get the type.  I cant seem to find a way to get there.  It feels like this should be very easy.

```
Dim infoReader As System.IO.FileInfo
infoReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo(txtFileName.Text)
```

FileInfo gets me modified data and size of the file.. but not the type.

Appreciate forums help!

. I.e. for .pdf file the display with would "adobe acrobat document" .xls file would be "Microsoft excel worksheet"

Comment: [C# version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780028/how-can-i-get-the-description-of-a-file-extension-in-net) of this question - you may be able to translate the C#.

Comment: Current NET versions include a [MimeMapping Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.aspx) or you could build a dictionary of common/expected mime types and look up the extension. Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the description of a file extension in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780028/how-can-i-get-the-description-of-a-file-extension-in-net)

Answer (score 4):

You can use below VB.net code for getting the file type description. Basically you have to use **SHGetFileInfo** API to get that information.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module Get_File_Type

Sub Main()
    Dim info As New NativeMethods.SHFILEINFO()

    Dim fileName As String = "C:\TEST\TEST.xlsx"
    Dim dwFileAttributes As UInteger = NativeMethods.FILE_ATTRIBUTE.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL
    Dim uFlags As UInteger = CUInt(NativeMethods.SHGFI.SHGFI_TYPENAME Or NativeMethods.SHGFI.SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES)

    NativeMethods.SHGetFileInfo(fileName, dwFileAttributes, info, CUInt(Marshal.SizeOf(info)), uFlags)

    Console.WriteLine(info.szTypeName)
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub

End Module

NotInheritable Class NativeMethods
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
    Public Structure SHFILEINFO
        Public hIcon As IntPtr
        Public iIcon As Integer
        Public dwAttributes As UInteger
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=260)> _
        Public szDisplayName As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=80)> _
        Public szTypeName As String
    End Structure

    Public NotInheritable Class FILE_ATTRIBUTE
        Private Sub New()
        End Sub
        Public Const FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL As UInteger = &H80
    End Class

    Public NotInheritable Class SHGFI
        Private Sub New()
        End Sub
        Public Const SHGFI_TYPENAME As UInteger = &H400
        Public Const SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES As UInteger = &H10
    End Class

    <DllImport("shell32.dll")> _
    Public Shared Function SHGetFileInfo(pszPath As String, dwFileAttributes As UInteger, ByRef psfi As SHFILEINFO, cbSizeFileInfo As UInteger, uFlags As UInteger) As IntPtr
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you Bob, it works great!  How do you come up with such code... Wow!

Comment: Your welcome mattrak, I am using similar code for getting file related information.

Comment: There's no need for all of this gibberish... There are other methods of doing such ... Also `Basically you have to use SHGetFileInfo API to get that information`, I strongly disagree with that statement. Do you ***not know of another way***?

Comment: @mattrak see [***here***](https://github.com/Raymai97/BadAPPLEanim/blob/master/SOURCE%20v2.0/baShared.vb), that's not the only place that code live's either; there are other places as well that have this; it's not new.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly this is all you would need...

```
Public Shared Function GetFileType(ByVal Extention As String) As String
   Return My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\" & My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\" & Extention, "", Extention).ToString, "", Extention).ToString
End Function
```

To use it just get the `extension` of your file and then pass that into the function.  Below will get your extension you would need.

```
IO.Path.GetExtension(YOUR FILE PATH HERE)
```

So all wrapped up...

```
 Dim strName As String = GetFileType(IO.Path.GetExtension(YOUR FILE PATH HERE))
```

Comment: Codexer, thank you Buddy!  It is amazing the different ways to skin the cat.  Your solution was lot simpler and infact I can understand what you are doing.  Thank you once again