# Reading file properties from windows file system?

Tags: c#, .net, directory, fileinfo

Would anyone be able to help me with how to get the file properties from a windows object, i.e., FileSize, FileType, Year, Label, DateModified,FileVersion. I have tried accessing the info in the FileInfo class and it appears it does not have all the necessary properties I'm looking for. Which other libraries could I use to access this information and if you could please provide examples, thank you

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220097/read-write-extended-file-properties-c

or

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5036/ID3-Tag-Reader-Using-Shell-Functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of that is already avaiable in FileInfo (Length is the file size, Date Modified is simply LastWriteTime). Some of the information is available from [FileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.aspx). The 'type' is kind of tricky, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111687/setting-mimetype-in-c-sharp) post has some info on looking the mime type up in the registry. This worked for me on windows 7:

```
private static string GetType(string fileName)
    {
        string type = "Unknown";
        string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName).ToLower();
        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(ext);
        if (regKey != null && regKey.GetValue("") != null)
        {
            string lookup = regKey.GetValue("").ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lookup))
            {
                var lookupKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(lookup);
                if (lookupKey != null)
                {
                    type = lookupKey.GetValue("").ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        return type;
    }
```

It will produce the Type you see in detail tab page of the file properties. For example, 'Application' for exe and 'Bitmap Image' for bmp.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437382/get-file-type-in-net) gets the type using the windows api function shgetfileinfo.

Answer (score 0):

Hey Check with MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.aspx

Example

```
GetCreationTime ()
GetLastWriteTime ()
```